# Git: How to rollback/undo a change to an image?

Tags: git, git-revert

So our designer made some changes to some images, and committed the changes. So now our `git log` looks something like this:

```
Commit 1: Changed images
Commit 2: Oops, forgot to commit a few images
```

...then the business wanted them to look different, so the designer changed them, and committed them again:

```
Commit 1: Changed images
Commit 2: Oops, forgot to commit a few images
Commit 3: Changed images again
Commit 4: Minor tweaks to new images just committed
```

...now the business decided that they liked the images better the first time. So now we need to roll back to the way they were near the beginning. I have tried a few different approaches and I think the approach I need to use is `git revert` so that I can create a new commit that reverts the images back to the way they were before. However, I seem to be having conflicts when I try to do this. How should I do this so that I can force the new images to be overwritten with the changes made in `Commit 1` and `Commit 2`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you want to do is check the file out from an old commit.

It'll look like:

```
git checkout <commit 1 refspec> imagefilename.png
```

that commit refspec might be HEAD{4} or might be a SHA or maybe a tag.... Something that refers to that commit. Then it'll be sitting in your working directory as a change to add and commit.

Answer (score 1):

If none of these are merge commits, then `git revert <Commit 3> <Commit 4>` should do the trick (where `<Commit X>` is the SHA1 of the commit). Do a `git stash` if you have uncommitted changes.

Alternatively, do `git checkout <Commit 2> -- <filenames of images to be restored>` followed by `git add` and a commit.